# DotNetNuke - DnnImageHandler.ashx - error 500

Tags: dotnetnuke

Clean Dnn Version : 09.01.01 (129)

When I work with Dnn and have javascript console opened, a lot of times I get error:

> /DnnImageHandler.ashx?mode=profilepic&userId=1&h=32&w=32 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

At the same time the image in the toolbar profile is missing. Where an how I can see what is working wrong what logs to check? If I go to ***Manage / Admin Logs*** and select ***Log Settings*** There is a lot of stuf I can enable, but dont know what can be right to see this error and try to find something more.

If I try to open this link in another browser window most of the time everithing is OK and I get generic user image with "?" back.

Also does anyone else see this errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the same error here:

https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-9581

It is fixed in dnn 9.2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18647734)

Comment: This is only link to the same official bug report with statement that in version 9.2 the bug is solved

Comment: @JernejPirc I have upgraded to 9.2.1 and the error is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

So I just spent the past hour trying to figure this out, and had to do a lot of cleanup on one of my DNN instances where it was occurring, but once I got all the cleanup done I think it comes down to this.

You're logged in with a Host/SuperUser account correct?

If you login as ANY other user, one of the Users in the Portal, it works correctly?

I ended up having to fix my "profile" page, the site was referencing skins that didn't exist anymore on the profile page, then containers that didn't exist. Once I cleaned all that up, I was able to navigate to the profile page, click on Edit profile, and once I edited the profile, I uploaded a new avatar for the HOST user and was able to get the image to render properly.

I think the issue has something to do with HOST accounts and either referencing an image that isn't part of the current portal, OR HOST accounts and referencing a default image that doesn't exist due to it being a host account, instead of a standard user account.

So how to fix?

Try uploading a profile photo for your account on the current portal and see if that resolves.

Comment: Thanks I will also try this and report back.

Comment: I upload user profile picture for a host but the problem still exists. If I open the link with error 500 in another tab/window or refresh the page the error goes away and then for some time I see the problem again?